# damaged drywall: Repair with spackle or replace drywall?

Tags: drywall, damage, spackling-paste

My dog scratched up part of our interior wall next to a door.  He tore off the molding around the door and also scratched some of the drywall off.  There are no holes in the drywall, but there are some scratches that go fairly deep into the drywall.  The area I am talking about is probably 3 inches wide and 3 ft tall.  Part of that area will be covered up by the molding.  Can I use spackle to repair this or is it better to just cut the damaged drywall out and replace it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use actual joint compound. I'm not sure what you're referring to with "spackle", but in my experience it's a very fluffy, soft product. Get some topping or repair compound and apply it twice (it'll shrink a bit), then sand lightly. Prime and paint.

It's not necessary to replace the panel or use joint tape for surface scratches, even if they're through the paper.

Comment: This stuff: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Onetime-8-oz-Lightweight-Spackling-0542HD/202314762

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking of using Joint Compound instead, but if I am not mistaken, they are fairly similar.  Spackle dries quicker, but I think its mainly for nail holes and stuff like that.  I used the term loosely to mean either spackle or joint compound...  The main question I had was either repairing the drywall or replacing it and you answered it perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Spackle's just fine. The real trick is replicating the texture!

Comment: yeah, that was my main concern.  I did not know if I would be able to get it to be completely flat and level with the rest of the wall.  That is why I was wondering if I should just replace the whole piece or if that was overkill